# How does a JSON object gets tokenized and indexed in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I recently started working on Elasticsearch and could not figure out how a JSON object gets tokenized and gets stored in the inverted index.

Consider below JSON has been inserted.

```
{
    "city": "Seattle",
    "state": "WA",
    "location": {
        "lat": "47.6062095",
        "lon": "-122.3320708"
    }
}
```

I can perform an URI search like this

```
GET /my_index/_search?q=city:seattle
```

This search would return the above document, but how does Elasticsearch could be able to search 'seattle' only in the 'city' field. If it tokenizes the complete JSON, all the keys and values would be separated, then how the mapping between key token and value token would be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Because the indexed tokens point to the original document, which is also stored.
Have a look at [Inverted Index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html) in the elastic docs.